# CSS grid 3 column layout, shrink center after margins have shrank to 0px

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I want to create a CSS grid responsive 3 column layout, with the center column 500px, and the margins taking up remaining space.

However, when the screen is resized so narrower than 500px, I want the center column to shrink, with the margins taking up no room at all (0px).

I have done this using the following code, but I found no other way than using a media query and fiddling around with the numbers!  I feel certain this should be possible with just using the grid-template-columns, but cant find a way.  Can anyone help.

```html
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    .grid {
      display: grid;
      margin: 20px;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 500px 1fr;
      align-items: stretch;
      justify-items: stretch;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 560px) {
      .grid {
        grid-template-columns: 0 1fr 0;
      }
    }
    
    .left {
      grid-column: 1;
      background-color: red;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    .centre {
      grid-column: 2;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .right {
      grid-column: 3;
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="centre"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Will the side columns contain content? Or serve only to align the middle column?

Comment: Yeh, they contain content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple when you discover the trick..

minmax(0,500px) tries to allocate as much room for the as possible, up to 500px, while allowing it to shrink if viewport is too narrow.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
.grid {
    display: grid;
    margin: 20px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(0,500px) 1fr;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-items: stretch;
}

.left {
    grid-column: 1;
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
}

.centre {
    grid-column: 2;
    background-color: green;

}

.right {
    grid-column: 3;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="centre"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    .grid {
      display: grid;
      margin: 20px;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .left {
      grid-column: 1;
      background-color: red;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    .centre {
      grid-column: 2;
      background-color: green;
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto 0;
      width: 100%
    }
    
    .right {
      grid-column: 3;
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="centre"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Do you want the left / right column fluid and then centre to just be 500px then margins auto?

Comment: If there is room, the centre needs to be set to 500px, and no more than 500px with the left/right fluid.  However, if there is no room for the centre to be 500px, the centre needs to be set to the maximum it can be, with the left/right set to 0.

Comment: It mimics the behaviour of the forecast table on the metoffice website here - https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/weather/forecast/gcj2x8gt4#?date=2019-09-10